# OneToOne Bi-Directional Mapping using Hibernate annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I want a Bi-Directional mapping on my 2 Entities(PersonDetail, 
   PassportDetail) but it seems that it doesn't work fine. I want that 
   PersonDetail has a PassportId and PassportDetail has a PersonId as well.

**My PersonDetail java Code**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="persondetail")
public class PersonDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="person_id")
private int id;

@Column(name="person_name")
private String name;

@Column(name="person_phone")
private long phone;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="person",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="passport_id")
private PassportDetail passport;

public PassportDetail getPassport() {
    return passport;
}

public void setPassport(PassportDetail passport) {
    this.passport = passport;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(long phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
@Column(name="passport_id")
private int passort_id;

public int getPassort_id() {
    return passort_id;
}

public void setPassort_id(int passort_id) {
    this.passort_id = passort_id;
}
}
```

**Here is my PassportDetail Java Code**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PassportDetail")
public class PassportDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="passport_id")
private int id;

@Column(name="passport_number")
private String passportNumber;

@Column(name="country_name")
private String country;

@Column(name="issue_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
private PersonDetail person;


public String getPassportNumber() {
    return passportNumber;
}

public void setPassportNumber(String passportNumber) {
    this.passportNumber = passportNumber;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public PersonDetail getPerson() {
    return person;
}

public void setPerson(PersonDetail person) {
    this.person = person;
}
}
```

**Here is the Output in MySql**
[Here is the Output of Both table as you can clearly see the problem i.e PersonDetail has a column named passport_id but it dosesn't have any value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTTEH.png)

**Here is the insertion code**

```
public class MappingMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PersonDetail person=new PersonDetail();
    PassportDetail passport = new PassportDetail();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

    person.setName("Ankit");
    person.setPhone(790148565);

    passport.setCountry("india");
    try {
    passport.setDate(sdf.parse("2018-04-15"));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    passport.setPassportNumber("QUJMZ123");
    passport.setPerson(person);
    person.setPassport(passport);

    PersonDao dao=new PersonDao();
    dao.save(person);

}
```

**Here is the DAO class**

```
public class MappingDao {

SessionFactory sf=Util.getSessionFactory();

public void save(UserDemo user)
{
    Session session=sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}
}
```

Comment: *I want that PersonDetail has a PassportId and PassportDetail has a PersonId*: no, you really don't want or need that. A single foreign key is sufficient. *Here is the output*: the output of what? What is the code inserting these two rows?

Comment: You can not have bi-directional relationship it will create a problem of cyclic dependency. It will not be possible to insert into either table due to foreign key constrains.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, so in every case a single foreign key is sufficient or there are some other cases where Bi-Directional mapping is required if so, Could you please tell me.
And the Output means the records in both tables(PersonDetail & PassportDetail) after execute this code.

Comment: *after execute this code*: which code? There is no single line of code posted that would insert two entities in the database. All we have is the entities. How you use them and save them matters.

Comment: @JBNizet I just inserted the insertion code. I appreciate it if you look at once. Thanks

Comment: OK, so your code works fine, since all you need is a single foreign key, (passport.person_id), and it is being populated. Just remove the `@JoinColumn(name="passport_id")` in Person, since it doesn't make sense: the association is**mapped by** the other side of the association.

Comment: @JBNizet thnx sir I appreciate it. It works.